# MySQL работа с JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, mysql-5.7

Немного не разобрался как строить таблицы более компактно, сорян)

---

В общем... и целом, задание, из таблицы deals выбрать кол-во строк по датам и по пользователям, в которых участвует obj или bid пользователя. Если в строке и obj и bid одного пользователя, то это 1(это в идеале, но можно и без этого).

---

Решить данную задачу я бы хотел сам, но нуждаюсь в подсказках, может есть какие статьи или вы можете, что-то подсказать?

---

Таблицы:
Deals

| id | obj | bid | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 2021-10-05 |
| 2 | 2 | 5 | 2021-10-05 |
| 3 | 3 | 4 | 2021-10-06 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 | 2021-10-06 |

obj

| id | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 6 |
| 4 | 7 |
| 5 | 8 |

bid

| id | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 5 | 8 |
| 6 | 8 |

Результат:

| created | user_id | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-05 | 5 | 2 |
| 2021-10-05 | 6 | 1 |
| 2021-10-05 | 8 | 1 |
| 2021-10-06 | 5 | 1 |
| 2021-10-06 | 6 | 1 |
| 2021-10-06 | 8 | 1 |

По вариантам, пока я додумался только до такого:

```
SELECT DATE(deals.date) as created, obj.user_id as user_id, count(deals.obj) as total 
FROM `deals` 
INNER JOIN obj ON obj.id = deals.obj
WHERE obj.user_id in (5,7) and DATE(deals.date) BETWEEN '2021-10-05' and '2021-10-06' 
GROUP BY obj.user_id, DATE(deals.date)
```

И такой же для таблицы bid, а затем уже в коде считать...
Может есть какие, подобные примеры где это выполнено одним запросом?

MySQL 5.7

Comment: UNION, потом агрегация. Или UNION агрегированных запросов (как показанный) и ещё одна агрегация снаружи.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, буду гуглить и пробовать)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Может я и растянул количество операций, но просто шёл по этапам.

**Этапы:**

1. `ALL` - аналог таблицы `Deals`, только сразу с `user_id`;
2. `DIFF` - сравнение пользователей;
3. `UNION` - разбитие таблицы на разные столбцы и объединение.
4. Вывод итоговой таблицы с подсчётом `total`

**Запрос:**

```
WITH ALL_CTE (date, obj_user_id, bid_user_id)
AS
(
SELECT
   D.date,
   O.user_id AS obj_user_id,
   B.user_id AS bid_user_id
FROM Deals D
JOIN obj O ON O.id = D.obj
JOIN bid B ON B.id = D.bid
),
DIFF_CTE (date, obj_user_id, bid_user_id, diff)
AS
(
SELECT
   date,
   obj_user_id,
   bid_user_id,
   CASE
      WHEN obj_user_id = bid_user_id
      THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END AS diff
FROM ALL_CTE
),
UNION_CTE (date, user_id, diff)
AS
(
SELECT
   date,
   obj_user_id AS user_id,
   diff
FROM DIFF_CTE
UNION ALL
SELECT
   date,
   bid_user_id AS user_id,
   diff
FROM DIFF_CTE
)
SELECT
   date AS created,
   user_id,
   CASE
      WHEN diff <> 1
      THEN COUNT(user_id)
      ELSE 1
   END AS total
FROM UNION_CTE
GROUP BY
   date,
   user_id,
   diff
```

**Результат:**
[image: RESULT]

**UPDATE:**
MySQL 5.7

```
SELECT 
   date  AS created,
   user_id,
   CASE
      WHEN diff <> 1
      THEN COUNT(user_id)
      ELSE 1
   END AS total
FROM
(SELECT date, user_id, diff FROM
(SELECT
   D.date,
   O.user_id AS user_id,
   CASE
      WHEN O.user_id = B.user_id
      THEN 1
      ELSE 0
   END AS diff
FROM Deals D
JOIN obj O ON O.id = D.obj
JOIN bid B ON B.id = D.bid) t_diff
UNION ALL
SELECT date, user_id, diff FROM
(SELECT
   D.date,
   B.user_id AS user_id,
   CASE
      WHEN O.user_id = B.user_id
      THEN 1
      ELSE 0
   END AS diff
FROM Deals D
JOIN obj O ON O.id = D.obj
JOIN bid B ON B.id = D.bid) t_diff) t_union
GROUP BY
   date,
   user_id,
   diff
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=60118e2aba59369976e5b01726524df2

Comment: Добрый день, спасибо за ответ, но если бы в таблице Deals(All) был бы user_id, проблемы бы небыло) Однако думаю на основе вашего варианта у меня что-то да получится)

Comment: Еще оказалось что версия MySQL 5.7 не знает оператора WITH.

Comment: @nAPrikoLe, 1 - в `Deals` и нет `user_id`, таблицы связаны с помощью `JOIN`. 2 - стоило указывать на чём БД и версию. Вы же проставили sql метку

Comment: @nAPrikoLe, добавил для MySQL 5.7

Comment: да вы гений) я бы до такого долго доходил) действительно работает и вроде как все прям как надо
А с версией действительно косяк, не подумал об этом, извиняюсь.
Жаль я не смог решить задачу самостоятельно, но я вас благодарю за помощь!